# Failed to publish application to Azure Service Fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to publish an application to Azure Service Fabric cluster. The moment I click publish from VS2015, I get those following errors:

*"An error occurred reading the file xxx\publishprofiles\cloud.xml. There is an error in XML document (7, 6)"*

*"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*

[image]

This is the content of the Cloud.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/05/fabrictools">
  <ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint=... />
  <ApplicationParameterFile Path="xxx\ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml" />
  <UpgradeDeployment Mode="Monitored" Enabled="true">
    <Parameters FailureAction="Rollback" Force="True" />
    <Parameters UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeoutSec="1" Force="True" />
  </UpgradeDeployment>
</PublishProfile>
```

It seems that I can have only one of the parameters (`FailureAction` OR `UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeoutSec`) for VS2015 to successfully load the file.

I wonder if anyone has some insights into this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be one Parameters element.  Combine all your parameters into just one Parameters element.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/05/fabrictools">
  <ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint=... />
  <ApplicationParameterFile Path="xxx\ApplicationParameters\Cloud.xml" />
  <UpgradeDeployment Mode="Monitored" Enabled="true">
    <Parameters FailureAction="Rollback" Force="True" UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeoutSec="1" />
  </UpgradeDeployment>
</PublishProfile>
```

Comment: For completeness, can you please provide an example ?

Comment: Updated my answer with example.

Comment: Oh nice. So what "Force="True" pertains to? Both?

Comment: Force is its own parameter, just like the others.  The parameters defined here correspond to the PowerShell parameters that you want to include as part of executing an upgrade of the application.  The available parameters are described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicefabric/vlatest/start-servicefabricapplicationupgrade.